# Delete files in S3 under a certain prefix using LifeCycle configuration

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have the following folder structure in S3.

```
dirA/dirB/inputs/
dirA/dirB/outputs/
dirA/dirB/someObject
```

Here dirA, dirB are just placeholders. They have multiple names. For example, this is how the bucket is organized:

```
folder1/subFolder1/inputs/
folder1/subFolder1/outputs/
folder1/subFolder1/someobject
 
folder2/subFolder2/inputs/
folder2/subFolder2/outputs/
folder2/subFolder2/someobject
```

I am looking to delete the objects under all `outputs/` after 1 day. I have the following Java code:

```
public void addLifeCycleRule() {
        try {
            BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule deleteObjectsRule = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration.Rule()
                    .withId("Delete outputs objects after 1 day")
                    .withFilter(new LifecycleFilter(new LifecyclePrefixPredicate("outputs/")))
                    .withExpirationInDays(1)
                    .withStatus(BucketLifecycleConfiguration.ENABLED);

            BucketLifecycleConfiguration configuration = new BucketLifecycleConfiguration()
                    .withRules(Collections.singletonList(deleteObjectsRule));

            s3Client.setBucketLifecycleConfiguration(bucketName, configuration);

        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            log.info("addLifeCycleRule: Exception occured. ex={}", e.getErrorMessage());
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            log.info("addLifeCycleRule: SdkClientException ex={}", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This somehow doesn't seem to apply to existing objects in S3. Any suggestions on what can be done here will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "This somehow doesn't seem to apply to existing objects in S3." How long did you wait? It won't be applied immediately.

Comment: It's been over three hours since the policy's been applied. I referred to a few other threads that said it could up to 48 hrs.

Comment: For a large S3 bucket, I've never seen it take less than 12 hours. I usually just create the policy and check it the next day.

Answer (score 0):

The AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) says that lifecycle changes would apply to both existing and future objects.